# Vector of pointer crashes program on increment

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, crash, iteration

I've been working on a project, and frankly I'm not very experienced with C++; but I did as much research as I could and tried four or five different for-loop setups.

shared_ptr, unique_ptr, *this, this.. Either the pointer is copied and changes made to it later aren't committed to the vector **or**, the vector manages to crash the program when the vector increments. int or iterator.

I can confirm that the `save()` function is not the source of issue because the `Logger::Event()` does print out after `save()`, but the Log should print again immediately after loop (function) exit as well. When the vector is confirmed (through `size()`) to have more than one item, it crashes after the first iteration.

Here is my trimmed DataFile.cpp:

```
vector<DataFile*> DataFile::allDataFiles;

void DataFile::saveAll(){
    Logger::Event("in SaveALL();");
    Logger::Event(to_string(allDataFiles.size()));
    for (vector<DataFile*>::iterator it = allDataFiles.begin(); it != allDataFiles.end(); it++){
        Logger::Event((*it)->_FILE);
        if ((*it)->saveOnClose) (*it)->save();
        Logger::Event("End of saveAll loop iteration.");
    }
}
DataFile::DataFile(string fn, bool r, bool soc){
    //...
    allDataFiles.push_back(move(this));
}
```

And from my DataFile.h

```
public:
        DataFile(std::string _fileName, bool readNow = true, bool saveOnClose = true);
        bool save();
        static void saveAll();
private:
    static std::vector<DataFile*> allDataFiles;
```

I am aware I'm not using the return value of `save()`, it's for future use. I am not currently using a debugger but am using the latest version of MinGW and MSYS to make from my Windows 8 laptop using NetBeans. As I said before the output of the above is as follows.

```
EV 19:04:34 Event:   in SaveALL();
EV 19:04:34 Event:   2
EV 19:04:34 Event:   tEST.aconf
EV 19:04:34 Event:   End of saveAll loop iteration.

RUN FAILED (exit value -1,073,741,819, total time: 4s)
```

Comment: I’m not really a C++ person but I’m pretty sure `move(this)` doesn’t do anything. `this` is a pointer. You’re probably letting it become invalid. Why not store `DataFile`s directly?

Comment: `move(this)` was more of a test to see if I could store a pointer to the object itself, as opposed to storing a copy of the object as it appears `push_back(this)` does.

Comment: `push_back(this)` stores a pointer, not a copy.

Comment: I ran some more tests and found that push_back(this) did prevent the crash, so you must've been right about invalidating the `this` pointer. Unfortunately though, using the above code and only changing `move(this)` to `this` results in the save operation not outputting any of the information added to `DataFile` after initialisation, as if I've modified a copy instead.
I have a new idea of where this might have happened, I'll be back in a few.